# Trying to Reorder Entries in a Row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a (poorly) self taught PHP developer, so go easy on me.  :)

I've got a tool I'm trying to create that collects entries in a row, and orders them so the NULL values end up at the end of the row.  So for example, if I have a row that looks like this

```
| LeaderID  | Person1 | Person2 | Person3 | Person4 | Person5 | Person6 |
|-----------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|   1       |   NULL  |   5     |    8    |   NULL  |    9    |    11   |
```

I want to be able to read the row of values and have it write back to the row the following:

```
| LeaderID | Person1 | Person2 | Person3 | Person4 | Person5 | Person6 |
|----------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|    1     |   5     |   8     |    9    |   11    |   NULL  |   NULL  |
```

Hopefully this makes sense but please ask if not.  I've searched and can't seem to find a solution to this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show some code on how you're generating this, and we might be able to help you.

Comment: you are talking about rows but you are showing columns, I'm not sure what you want to do here... is this a database, or just an array with key/values?

Comment: How/why does `person4` change from `NULL` to `11`? Shouldn't `person4` always have the same value?

Comment: Sorry for my poor question asking abilities!

Comment: It's okay! Learning is part of the process. Check out the [tour] and how to ask a good [mcve] question.

Comment: @NDM The first row is the column title.  The second row is the values.  This is just the table structure.   And no, I don't want person4 to always have a value of 11.  What other info can I provide?

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of a SELECT that won't be the length of a novel, but this series of UPDATEs could be used to change your data (permanently) or used on a temporary copy of your data, to get what I think you want.

```
UPDATE theTable SET Person1 = Person2, Person2 = NULL WHERE Person1 IS NULL;
UPDATE theTable SET Person2 = Person3, Person3 = NULL WHERE Person2 IS NULL;
UPDATE theTable SET Person3 = Person4, Person4 = NULL WHERE Person3 IS NULL;
UPDATE theTable SET Person4 = Person5, Person5 = NULL WHERE Person4 IS NULL;
UPDATE theTable SET Person5 = Person6, Person6 = NULL WHERE Person5 IS NULL;
```

This won't guarantee what you want on the first pass; you may need to repeat this series of updates five or six times to "trickle" all values (depends on how many adjacent nulls there are).

It could actually be done in a single query, but it would be much much more complicated than this.

Comment: Thanks Uueerdo!  How would I know when to stop running the Updates? Wouldn't this have to be done manually?

Comment: @NorthernWolf when there are no "rows affected" in the entire batch, you are done. If you don't want to track that then... If Person1-5 were initially null, the value in Person6 gets moved "up" one spot each "batch". So, assuming Person6 is the last spot, you are guaranteed to be done in 5 "batches". _My intuition tells me the exact number needed for a set of rows is equal to the highest number of null values in a row in that set modulus the number of value fields possible in a row._